# Is it possible to get an android media player to display an image

Tags: android, image, video, imageview, media-player

I want to use an android media player to display both pictures and videos, I have it displaying videos but can't find a way to get it to display pictures, is it even possible?

I tried putting in an image view but it didn't work too well with the surface view and kept crashing or not displaying the image.

Comment: You should post some code for help. Maybe I can help you to show it in  a ImageView

Comment: I have a solution that uses canvas, which also uses the surface view, but it would be easier if I could use the media player